# Tour of Go Exercise #8: Loops and Functions

Tags: go

I am trying to solve the exercise [#8](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/8) of the Go Tour.

My solution fails with an error message `the process to take too long`

What is wrong ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func Sqrt(x float64) float64 {
    guess := 1.0
    i := 1
    for i < 10 {
        guess = guess - (math.Pow(guess, 2)-x)/(2*guess)
    }
    return guess
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(Sqrt(2))
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not incrementing the `i` variable in your loop, so it's always `< 10`.

```
 //-----------v
for ; i < 10; i++ {
    guess = guess - (math.Pow(guess, 2)-x)/(2*guess)
}
```